# How does the value for Spearman’s rank influence the shape of a scatter graph?

Tags: statistics, correlation

So I have been looking at correlation recently, but I was confused about what the values for Spearman’s rank actually mean for a scatter diagram.

For example, for Pearson’s product moment correlation coefficient, I know a value of 0.95 means a scatter diagram that has a strong, positive correlation, a value close to 0 means no correlation and a value of -0.3 means a weak negative correlation.

Could someone give a similar explanation (or diagram) to help me understand what a Spearman’s rank value of 0.95, 0 and -0.3 actually mean for a scatter diagram?

Many thanks.

Comment: Spearman's rank correlation is also a Pearson's correlation.

Comment: How would you go about sketching a graph with $r>-1$ and $r_s=-1$?